# PHP: How to process File Names that Contain the # number sign?

Tags: php, special-characters, filenames, file-handling

I'm working on a little Project to give some audio data a web interface.
I'm reading the content of existing folders with PHP.

Here's my PHP Code:

```
<?php
$mp3folder = 'mp3/';
$oggfolder = 'ogg/';
$mp3files = glob($mp3folder.'*.mp3');
$oggfiles = glob($oggfolder.'*.ogg');
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [';


for ($i=0; $i<count($mp3files); $i++) {
    $namerr[$i] = substr($oggfiles[$i],strlen($oggfolder),strpos($oggfiles[$i], '.')-strlen($oggfolder));
    echo '{'."\n";
    echo 'title:"'.$namerr[$i].'",'."\n";
    echo 'mp3:"'.$mp3files[$i].'",'."\n";
    echo 'ogg:"'.$oggfiles[$i].'"'."\n";
    echo '},'."\n";
}
echo '
    ], {
        swfPath: "../../_res/jplayer",
        supplied: "ogg, mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
});
</script>';

?>
```

I have directory structure built like this:

```
AUDIO
 -> index.php
 -> OGG
   -> SONG#1.ogg
   -> SONG#n.ogg
   -> SONG FUN. ogg
 -> MP3
   -> SONG#1.mp3
   -> SONG#n.mp3
   -> SONG FUN.mp3
```

The php code above successfully reads the audio files and build a list out of it, so jPlayer can read them and show playlists out of it.
**Problem is:** jPlayer won't read the audio files, when the file name contains a "#" sign. 
When I try to play "SONG #1.mp3" and then look at the debugger in Chromium it says "File SONG " not found, while it normally outputs something like "File 'SONG FUN.mp3' successfully read".

So my conclusion is that PHP has some kind of problem reading file names that contain a "#".

Or could jPlayer be the problem here?

BTW: this is my first PHP Project, so please be indulgent if there are many mistakes. I'm sure there are different and much better ways to approach this. But I'm a learner.

regards!

Comment: First off, there's no reason your file names should contain `#` in them. Second, you can try to escape it using `\#`. Not sure about it though

Comment: Thanks for answer! With that solution i would have to rename all files to `SONG \#1.mp3` right? I named the files like this because the file system never complained.. wasn't aware that it would cause problems.

Comment: I find your conclusion very strange. You basically say that PHP outputs the filenames correctly. But then your jPlayer is unable to read the correct names. Then you go on and say "So my conclusion is that PHP has some kind of problem reading file names that contain a "#""... huh? You just said that PHP returns a *correct* filelist. So your conclusion should instead be that it is a problem wit jPlayer . . .

Comment: Looking closer at the jPlayer source it seems to create anchors (<a>-tags) containing the url to your mp3 inside its href attribute. Inside URLs, a hashtag (#) references a local object (id) on the same page and is not considered to be part of a filename. Parsing the url for the filename would strip the hashtag part, and as such leave you with the problem you're seeing. So... in short: don't use a hashtag in your filenames ;)

Comment: hmm.. thanks @Tularis. Good Point! And I guess you're right with that. I looked into the "View Page Source" Tab in Firefox and the JavaScript data that the php generates look right: `mp3:"mp3/SONG #3.mp3",` but jPlayer won't play the file. So, how can I correct jPlayer ;-) ?!

Comment: do you think putting putting the .mp3 name in quotation marks would solve the problem in `<a href>`?

Comment: Perhaps, as suggested earlier, you can escape it. Alternatively you could encode the character. Putting it inside more quotes won't fix anything.

Comment: Just `urlencode()` the file names & see what jPlayer makes of it. (`SONG%231.ogg`).

Comment: @Wrikken could you explain this a little further? how could I add urlencode to my example? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: => `echo 'mp3:"'.dirname($mp3files[$i]).'/'.urlencode(basename($mp3files[$i])).'",'."\n";`. On a side note: I'd prefer it to only build an array it that `foreach`, and `echo urlencode(json_encode($that_array));`, to make sure proper escaping etc. is already done automagically, but save that for later.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks again for the `code`. It did _not_ work when i copy+pasted it. Fx gave me a parsing error, saying `syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO...` for next line after yours. I then added another `;` at the end. The Parsing Error is now gone, but jPlayer refuses to play any Songs, it's now looking for something like `mp3/song+%232.mp3"` - Even the files without `#` won't play. But I feel I'm (you're) near a solution. BTW. I did not understand much about `foreach`, `echo` and `urlencode(json_encode($that_array));`. If you like, give me link about that. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Hm, could you give me the json output of a single song with `#` in the name that won't play now you use the `urlencode`ing? (BTW: that url-encoding should probably work once we figure out what other error now presents itself: [the documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/) specifically mentions: _"The URLs given must conform to standard URL Encoding Rules."_.

Comment: This is the json for "song #2": `mp3:"mp3/song+%232.mp3",` – i'm afraid i should read more docs, by far more.. thanks again for your help.

Comment: btw: did i do right correcting the parsing error by adding a ";" like this `echo 'mp3:"'.dirname($mp3files[$i]).'/'.urlencode(basename($mp3files[$i])).'",'."\n";‌​;`

Comment: Hm, drop those `‌​‌​`'s: SO adds those for me when it thinks I write a line that's too long, they weren't meant to be there :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You to everyone who helped me on this! Especially Thanks to @Wrikken

I guess I finally figured it out: 
when I used `urlencode()` to transform the URLs into a proper form, i had the problem that spaces where converted to `+` signs where they should rather be transformed into `%20`. 
That is - as I understand it - mainly because of the fact that `urlencode()` is used for queries, so things like `index.php?search=Hello+World`.

**The Solution** was to use `rawurlencode()` instead.

So the Part of code in question now looks like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($mp3files); $i++) {
$namerr[$i] = substr($oggfiles[$i],strlen($oggfolder),strpos($oggfiles[$i], '.')-strlen($oggfolder));
echo '{'."\n";
echo 'title:"'.$namerr[$i].'",'."\n";
echo 'mp3:"'.dirname($mp3files[$i]).'/'.rawurlencode(basename($mp3files[$i])).'",'."\n";
echo 'ogg:"'.dirname($oggfiles[$i]).'/'.rawurlencode(basename($oggfiles[$i])).'",'."\n";
echo '},'."\n";
}
```

Thanks for all the good comments!

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer i sa jquery based application. It treats the filenames you output as actual URLs. In the case of URLs, a hashtag denotes a local ID which is not part of the filename. For example http://www.example.com/dir/file#id would return only "file" as the filename, not including the #id!

So your problem can be seen in two ways:

1. It's caused by alimitation in jPlayer, which in turn is caused by a limitation in the definition of an URL, or
2. it's caused by you using a # in a place where it's not allowed.

Since you can't change the way URLs are defined, you'll have to change your filenames not to include hashtags.